# Definition of Lebesgue number

Tags: general-topology

I cannot understand the definition of Lebesgue number.

Definition:

Let $R$ be an open cover for a metric space $M$. A number $e>0$ is called a Lebesgue number if for all $x \in M$ there exist $U(x) \in R$ such that $B_e(x)$ is inside $U(x)$. What I dont understand is that for all $e>0$ we can choose $U(x)=B_e(x)$ so every number is a Lebesgue number?

Comment: The cover is given. The set $U(x)$ is chosen from the given cover, you can't choose $U(x) = B_\varepsilon(x)$, since that does in general not belong to $R$.

Comment: But isn't it that Be(x) in the metric space M should only contain points of M? As d(x,y) is not defined outside M?

Comment: Lebesgue number is always defined w.r.t a given open cover here $R$ i.e a collection of open sets whose union contains the whole space here $M$.

Comment: Let $M = (0,1)$. Take $R = \{ (0,1/n) : n = 2, 3, \dots \} \bigcup (1/3, 1)$. Now take some $x < 1/3$, for any $\epsilon > 1/2$, there exists no open set containing $x$ (i.e. $U(x)$) in $R$ such that $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U(x)$ holds !!

Comment: Can you tell me a specific x in B(x) st x is not in U(x) for any U(x) in the above example